# No entities are Returned using Microsoft Academic API

Tags: python, api, academic-graph

I used the following API call to get the information from Microsoft Academic API:
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Ti=='bayesian modelling of student misconceptions in the one-digit multiplication with probabilistic programming.'
I get the following message:
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:8d5cbad1-6ca8-4d39-8271-8f3a8d671eae
Date: Sun, 31 May 2020 10:49:04 GMT
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 157
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "expr": "Ti=='bayesian modelling of student misconceptions in the one-digit multiplication with probabilistic programming.'",
  "entities": [],
  "timed_out": false
}
No entities are returned.Don't know why.Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if I search like this (without the hyphen between *one* and *digit*):

```
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?&expr=Ti==%27bayesian%20modelling%20of%20student%20misconceptions%20in%20the%20one%20digit%20multiplication%20with%20probabilistic%20programming%27&attributes=AA.AuN,AA.AuId,DOI,Ti,VFN,Y&orderby=Y:desc&subscription-key={YOUR-KEY}
```

If you are unsure about the exact title, but know the first words, then you could add three dots `...` after the shortened `Ti`-value (and before the next field), as in:
`expr=Ti='bayesian modelling of student misconceptions'...&attributes={YOUR-ATTRIBUTES}`.